# How do I get the roles of the currently logged-in user?

Tags: 7, users

In Drupal 8 I would use the following code.

```php
$current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$roles = $current_user->getRoles();
```

What is the equivalent code I should use in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current user in D7 via the global $user object

```
global $user;
$roles = $user->roles;
```